# Navigation - photo albums & chat

Tags: navigation, chat, photos

We are currently building a community site (hobby-project) and are having some issues with some ux-patterns.

Our site has a header with some navigation, left sidebar used for filters or other stuff (depending on the page you're viewing) and a main content zone.

Let's say you search for a profile.
- Click on 'Search' in the header
- Set your preferences
- All matching profiles are displayed in the main content area as 'thumbs' (profilecards as we call them).
- Clicking on a profile makes your maincontent to display full details. It has a link to get back to the search results.

Now, this presents two levels of navigation in the main content area. 
If we want to start a conversation (chat-style) or view a photo album of the profile, what would be the best way to display it?

1. Main content (RED), expand the 'breadcrumb' navigation to het back to the profile-details.
2. Present a photo-album in a popup (FB-style), same for a chat-window.

[image: List of profiles]
[image: Profile detail]

Comment: Do you have a rough sketch of this idea? I'm having trouble visualising this.

Comment: @Wendy, I just added 2 screens ... when clicking Photo-album or chat ... what's the best place to put the content ... when looking at it now, i'd say a popup ;-)

Comment: I'd make the profile detail page a separate page, keeping the breadcrumb display as you have it now (also mobile friendly). There's no need to make this an inlay of a search result page, especially if you have interactions in it that go into an even deeper level. You also can use that empty space on the left then. The photo album could be a pop-up. You'll also have more freedom to make this a distinctly different page, which is especially useful if people have personal things to share.

Comment: ok, so an album popup, makes navigating back easier. When viewing details, the left side will probably be used to view some ads. It contains some filtering on profiles and other content, depending on the page you view, it's not part of the search page.